# How to create a JSON file from several dictionaries and one list in python

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, flask-restful

I'm trying to create a JSON file in the following format:

```
[
{
  "startTimestamp" : "2016-01-03 13:55:00",
  "platform" : "MobileWeb",
  "product" : "20013509_825",
  "ctr" : 0.0150 
},
{...}
]
```

And the values are stored in the following way:

- `startTimeStamp` is in a list called `timestampsJSON`
- `platform` is in a dictionary in this form `productBoughtPlatform[product] = platform`
- `product` is in a dictionary in this form `productBoughtCount[product] = count`
- `ctr` is in a dictionary in this form `CTR_Product[product] = ctr`

I was trying to make something of the kind:

```
response = json.dumps({"startTimestamp":ts, for ts in timestampsJSON.items()
            "platform":plat, for plat in productBoughtPlatform.items()
            "product":pro, for pro, key in productBoughtCount.items()
            "ctr":ctr, for ctr in CTR_Product.items()})
```

I know the syntax is invalid, but can somebody suggest a way to structure this data in a JSON? Thanks!

Comment: To make sure I understand, the values being lists, what you are looking to do is take each item from each list, and associate them to their corresponding key, eventually resulting in a list of dictionaries. Each dictionary is ultimately the example you show. Is that correct?

Comment: Can you show what you have tried so far? You could be really close in your implementation and it just needs another pair of eyes. Explain what is breaking in your code, as well.

Comment: Using **zip()** function may help a lot to solve this problem.

Comment: Pretty much so. The problem is that the timestamps values are inside a list, the platform values are inside a dictionary value, and the product is a key inside a dictionary. Same as the platform value, the ctr is inside a dictionary. I tried first showing the timestamps, but it only showed one value (the last one of the list):

`response = {"startTimestamp":ts for ts in timestampsJSON} ` and the output is: `{"startTimestamp": "2016-02-01 23:11:00"}`

Comment: Can you please show the complete **timestampsJSON**? Definitely it will show like that as dictionary cannot have duplicated keys which you are already doing in your code.

Comment: That is the thing, timestampsJSON isn't a dictionary, it's a list, and that's how I'm retrieving the values: 
`for i in timestampsJSON:
        print(i)`
And I get the following:
`2016-02-01 00:11:00
2016-02-01 01:11:00
2016-02-01 02:11:00
2016-02-01 03:11:00
2016-02-01 04:11:00
2016-02-01 05:11:00
...
2016-02-01 23:11:00`

Comment: Okay so instead of following that approach do this: `[("startTimestamp", ts) for ts in timestampsJSON]` for all. Let me answer this with a little example.

Comment: **@William**, I have just used **zip()** and **list comprehension** and tried to present you a little example. Please have a look and comment if you couldn't solve.

Answer (score 0):

**@William**, here I have presented a simple example. Please have a look into it any try the same.

> Use all your lists as parameters of  **zip()**.

```
import json

dates = ["2018-2-5", "2017-7-5", "2016-5-2"]
ages = [23, 45, 34]
names = ["William Studart", "Rishikesh Agrawani", "Tam Fransis"]

output = [{"myDate": d, "myAge": a, "myName": n} for d, a, n in zip(dates, ages, names)]

print(json.dumps(output, indent=4))
```

**Output:**

```
[
    {
        "myName": "William Studart",
        "myAge": 23,
        "myDate": "2018-2-5"
    },
    {
        "myName": "Rishikesh Agrawani",
        "myAge": 45,
        "myDate": "2017-7-5"
    },
    {
        "myName": "Tam Fransis",
        "myAge": 34,
        "myDate": "2016-5-2"
    }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

@William, you need to know the relation between your timestamps and your product events. In your example, you have on one hand your list, which is ORDERED, and dicts, which are NOT. As your dicts all have products as keys, you have to link the products to your timestamps. 
Assuming you have a list of product events related to the timestamps in the same order, you want a list of dicts :

```
output=
[
  {
    "startTimestamp" : timestampsJSON[i],
    "platform" : productBoughtPlatform[products[i]],
    "product" : products[i],
    "ctr" : CTR_Product[products[i]] 
  } 
  for i in range(len(timestampsJSON))]

response = json.dumps(output)
```

should do the job. You can adapt to your relation between the timestamps and the products. If you have already a dict of events of the form :

```
events={
  "2016-02-01 00:11:00":"20013509_825",
  "2016-02-01 01:11:00":"20013509_826",
  "2016-02-01 02:11:00":"20013509_825",
  "2016-02-01 03:11:00":"20013509_827"
}

#you build your output list
output=[
  {
    "startTimestamp" : timestamp,
    "platform" : productBoughtPlatform[product],
    "product" : product,
    "ctr" : CTR_Product[product] 
  } 
  for timestamp,product in events.iteritems()]

response = json.dumps(output)
```